# I want to make music app (recording voice playback piano or guitar)

Tags: android, audio, fft

I want to make music app (android)

user recording voice and app is change piano or guitar sound

so i made recording part and recording voice analyze using FFT.

The problem is how to play instrument sound?

if using Thread , can't play changed beat just play sound regularly.

i use sound file to play instrument sound(.mid, .wave ... etc) in raw folder

plz help me, how to play instrument sound??

Answer (score 0):

One common way of doing this is using audio analysis and resynthesis.  For analysis you would use a pitch estimation algorithm (not just an FFT).  Then you might feed the output of the audio analysis (estimated pitch, bandwidth, amplitude, etc.) to a real-time music instrument waveform synthesis module used to feed the audio output, usually using short buffers (some number of milliseconds) on a periodic callback.  There are many many synthesis algorithms of varying quality.

This technique appears to be used by several iOS/iPhone apps.  Not sure about the latest Android APIs, but with earlier Android versions, the min latency permitted by the OS API was reported as long and not very good.